# Does any matrix integral with arbitrary potential has a 2D gravity dual?

Tags: gravity, matrix-model

Regarding the duality between matrix ensembles and gravity, the relationship has indeed been discussed in various papers, including arXiv:1903.11115, arXiv:1907.03363, and arXiv:2006.13414, among others.

In the paper arXiv:1903.11115, the author showed that the Dyson ensemble with $\beta = 2$ and a double scaling density proportional to $\sinh(2\pi\sqrt{E})$ exhibits a specific duality. However, it is important to note that this result pertains to a specific ensemble and potential.

As for the general question of whether any ensemble with an arbitrary potential among the ten ensembles (including the three Dyson $\beta$-ensembles and the seven $(\alpha,\beta)$-ensembles of Altland and Zirnbauer) has a dual 2D gravity,